# twitter bootstrap 3.0 responsive utilities classes to display in medium and large view only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I want to display only in medium and large breakpoints and based on twbs 3.0 documentation, its not possible using their breakpoint utilities class as seen here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

I can hide the divs when not in medium and large views

```
@media(max-width: @screen-md) {
   display:none;
}
```

But is there a way to accomplish it using their utilities classes like .visible-lg, etc?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any utility classes to acheive this. I've managed to do this by making the changes below in the less files...

in "variables.less" change the following vars -

```
@screen-xs     99999px;
@screen-sm     99999px;
```

at the bottom of "grid.less" add in the following -

```
.container {
    width:@screen-md;
}

@media (min-width: @screen-lg-desktop) {
    .container {
        width: @container-lg-desktop;
    }
}
```

When you recompile, it should only switch between the large and medium breakpoints.